# CSS changes on scroll, but with the scroll speed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, scroll

I want to do the usual "header changes on scroll". Right now the "change" animation is pure CSS3 Animation, which means that the animation runs on its own, but I want it to run simultaneous to the speed of the scrolling.

Right now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("scroll",function(){
        if($(document).scrollTop()>100){
            $("#header").removeClass("large").addClass("small");
        } else{
            $("#header").removeClass("small").addClass("large");
        }
    });
</script>
```

This is what I did (and you can see why I want to have animation/scrolling connected):
http://thomasmaier.me/beispiel/

This is an example of what I want: http://www.apple.com/imac-with-retina/. (you might have to wait a bit until the huge wallpaper appears. When you scroll, the css changes at the same speed as the scrolling).

How can I do this (with jQuery)? (I am no pro) Or do you have a better, more beautiful solution?

Best

Thomas

Answer (score 1):

Add the HTML attribute(onscroll) to which ever parent block you will be doing your scrolling.

//HTML BLOCK

```
<main onscroll = myfunction(event) </main>   //make sure you pass the event parameter
```

//JS BLOCK

```
function myfunction(e){
   window.MainBlock = e.target; //set event element to a variable
   window.ScrollVert = e.scrollY; //live feed of vertical scroll position

   //add simple if statement based on values to change zoom value based on the scrollY.
   MainBlock.style.zoom = "100%"
}
//CSS BLOCK
.main {
  zoom: 150%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to replicate a similar effect as the Mac retina webpage, I would try to catch the function event, and instead of animating the logo ("Neue Liberale") with classes, I would adjust it's size and only let the window scroll if the size of the logo has been reduced to a certain size.

For example, your logo on page load is 442px wide, let's assume you want to shrink it by 25% before launching the class animation and letting the user scroll down.

### CSS:

```
html.noscroll,
body.noscroll {
    overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

### JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("hmtl, body").addClass("noscroll");
    // Storing variables under window so they can be accessed by other scripts as well
    window.logoWidth = $("#logo").width();
    window.animated = false;
    // 'animateOnce' Will run the logo animation only once if set to true
    window.animateOnce = false;
});

$(document).on("mousewheel", function (e) {
    var switchClass = function() {
            $("html, body").removeClass("noscroll");
            if ($(document).scrollTop() > 10) {
                $("#logo").removeAttr("style");
                $("#header").removeClass("large").addClass("small");
            } else {
                $("#header").removeClass("small").addClass("large");
            }
        };
    if( e.originalEvent.wheelDeltaY > 0 ) {
        switchClass();
        return true;
    }  else {
        var animate = window.animated;
        if( !animate ) {
            var targetW = window.logoWidth * 0.75,
                currW = $("#logo").width(),
                // You can seed the animation up or down by changing the 'increment' (the higer the faster)
                increment = 0.20;
            if( currW > targetW ) {
                $("#logo").width( currW - (currW * increment) ); 
                return false;
            } else {
                if( window.animateOnce )
                    window.animated = true;
                switchClass();
                return true; 
            }
        } else {
            switchClass();
        }
    }
});
```

### JSFiddle:

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Marventus/92xxyt27/) for reference.

Comment: Thank you, that goes the right direction. But it seems like it doesn't change with the scroll speed but far too slow. Also it only works once. Once you scroll back up and down and up and down it's the old handling again that I have now. Can you fix that code to this way? That would be awesome!

Comment: No pb! You can't really detect scroll speed with this solution, AFAICT, since in order for the content not to scroll, you have to set the overflow to `hidden`, but you can adjust the speed manually by increasing the `increment` value. As for the animation running only once, if you set `window.animateOnce` to `false` it will animate every time you scroll, not just the first time.

Comment: I updated the code and the fiddle to fix a few quirks:
1. Detection of scroll down event (so the animation only fires on scroll down);
2. `animateOnce` option is now working as expected.